# how does google recovers the web site description?

Tags: seo

do you know how google recovers the description of a website in their search results? is it the meta-description? the first paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their algorithms aren't officially released to the public, but if there is a meta description tag, it takes that. Otherwise it generally depends on where the keywords lie within the body of the webpage. If someone is searching for "foo", a paragraph with foo in it will likely appear, with foo highlighted in bold.

Comment: I have read recently that google has started executing/interpreting sites javascript additionally now which I am interested in finding out what they actually do with the results of such.

Comment: Well, it would help for ajax content, plus I'm sure it's useful for a tonne of other stuff like load time and what the site is actually doing to users.

Answer (score -1):

Search Engines (including Google) crawl through the first introductory paragraph of the page or a post and takes that excerpt to put in the description when search results are shown. But there's a protection measure that one should take to be SEO friendly. If you are starting your page/post with an image, it negatively affects the SEO of that page because the search results are in text form and for that search engines won't understand the format of the image since they want a text description. In case of WordPress, use All IN One SEO Pack Plugin to manipulate the description if you are starting your post/page with an image.